# authentication error Azure speech to text

Tags: azure, speech-to-text

I have checked the other Q&A in SO but their answers did not help.
I'm running the example code for speech to text. I have tried REST, Python and JavaSript and in all of them I get 401 errors. I even logged the errors but did not find anything helpful.
I'm running with a free version and inside a network which is not public. I tried it once with a public network and got the same error. But the following code is run in the private. I don't find any document saying I need to setup inbound calls setup in my network.

```
import sys
sys.path
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
print("hello from Azure")
import os
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio import AudioOutputConfig


def recognize_from_microphone():
    print(os.environ.get('SPEECH_KEY'))
    print(os.environ.get('SPEECH_REGION'))
    print(os.environ.get('COGNITIVE_SERVICE_KEY'))
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=os.environ.get('SPEECH_KEY'), region=os.environ.get('SPEECH_REGION'))
    speech_config.speech_recognition_language="en-US"
    speech_config.set_property(speechsdk.PropertyId.Speech_LogFilename, "LOGS.txt")

    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    print("Speak into your microphone.")
    speech_recognition_result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()

    # speech_recognition_result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()

    if speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        print("Recognized: {}".format(speech_recognition_result.text))
    elif speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
        print("No speech could be recognized: {}".format(speech_recognition_result.no_match_details))
    elif speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = speech_recognition_result.cancellation_details
        print("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
        if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
            print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))
            print("Did you set the speech resource key and region values?")

recognize_from_microphone()
```

The error:

Error details: WebSocket upgrade failed: Authentication error (401). Please check subscription information and region name. SessionId:

Answer (score 0):

Source Code from the given [**MS Doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windows,terminal&pivots=programming-language-python).

**Code:**

```py
import sys
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import os
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio import AudioOutputConfig

def recognize_from_microphone():
    subscription_key = "<your_key>"
    region = "<your_region>"

    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=subscription_key, region=region)
    speech_config.speech_recognition_language = "en-US"
    speech_config.set_property(speechsdk.PropertyId.Speech_LogFilename, "LOGS.txt")

    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    print("Speak into your microphone.")
    speech_recognition_result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()

    if speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        print("Recognized: {}".format(speech_recognition_result.text))
    elif speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
        print("No speech could be recognized: {}".format(speech_recognition_result.no_match_details))
    elif speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = speech_recognition_result.cancellation_details
        print("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
        if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
            print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))
            print("Did you set the speech resource key and region values?")

recognize_from_microphone()
```

**Output:**
It prompts ***Speak into your microphone.***  like below,

[image]

***I got the text output of what I spoke,***

[image]

I got the **LOG.txt** file as below,

[image]